# About WP's save_post action

Tags: query, save-post, comparison

Quick question, in API's some times `save_post` is used(most of the time actually).
Is `save_post` the equivalent of the query action `INSERT INTO` whereas `save_post` saves metadata and forces Wordpress to do the rest of the work when used correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, "save_post" saves along with the meta_data which is stored in $_POST, $_GET or $post_data  and then it is inserted into the posts table . let me know if that's helpful.

Comment: I know i'm probably not as experienced in WP as most, so yes that makes it clearer for me it was indeed helpful. Thanks!(Can't accept answer yet)

Comment: cool , happy hacking !!